# Error in vb6 query

Tags: mysql, vb6, runtime-error

Here's the code;

```
Private Sub txtNProdname_Click()

Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With Rs
.ActiveConnection = Conn
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.CursorType = adOpenStatic
.LockType = adLockPessimistic
.Source = "SELECT proddescription FROM products WHERE prodsupplier=" & "'" &       txtNsupplier.Text & "' AND prodname=" & "'" & txtNProdname.Text & "'"
.Open

 txtNdescription.Text = Rs("proddescription")

 End With

End Sub
```

Error:

```
Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted.Requested operation requires a current record.
```

Cau help me? It seems like without the `AND` it will work but when i put it, the error occurs.

Comment: It would seem that no records satisfy the criteria including the AND expression.

Comment: how can i code if there is no matched record? If there is no matched record then exit, I've tried if else but it always has error like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After opening the recordset, you need to move to the first record prior to using it:

```
Rs.Open
If Rs.EOF = False Then
   Rs.MoveFirst
   txtNdescription.Text = Rs("proddescription")
End If
```